# Pushing branch when rebasing from master

Tags: git, git-rebase

We are a development team of 5 people.  We have a master branch and whenever we work on something new we just create a new branch. When we're done making that change,  we push the branch up to GitLab and do a merge/pull request so it gets merged with the master again.

I have a branch on my machine that I've been working on for about a week. In that week there has been changes to master, so I do this command on my branch:

```
git rebase master
```

Once that's done, I do this to push my new branch up:

```
git push origin some-branch
```

When I do that, I get this error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I do what it suggests, I do a `git pull origin some-branch`. Now the files I changed have been modified with `===HEAD>` text. So I fix that, and recommit my work.

Then, I try to do `git push origin some-branch` again and the exact same error comes out.

To make it a little more clear, `git status` on some-branch returns:

```
# On branch some-branch
# Your branch and some-branch have diverged,
# and have 3 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
```

How can I fix this, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be force-pushing your branch as opposed to merging the changes in. That is, use `git push -f` after you rebase.

When you perform a rebase, you are telling Git to replay the history of master onto your branch, and subsequently, the commits of your branch need to fall in place after the work that was replayed.

This *changes the history* of that branch, which explains why you are seeing the divergence message in `git status`, but this is entirely intentional.  However, in merging that in with your remote branch, you are *greatly* confusing your history; it now contains merge commits that should never have existed.

Use a force-push instead next time, but be *certain* that the work that you've rebased onto passes your tests, be they smoke tests, unit/integration tests, or otherwise.

Comment: And be sure no one else is pushing to that same remote branch.

Answer (score -2):

You can try create a stash for the local changes before make the pull...

```
$ git commit -m "your commit" 
$ git stash
$ git pull
$ git stash apply
$ git push
```

Comment: That's not really going to help in this scenario.